# expected value of win in a die toss game

Tags: probability

Suppose we flip two die and if the maximum number of them greater than 4 we will win a coin. Otherwise we will loose a coin.
We repeat this game at n times

I want to find the expected number of coins we win in stage 1 and stage n.
I think that they are both the same and are equal 1/9.

Also I want to find the expected value that I win in stage 1 if I loose at stage n. I can't understand whether they are independent or not. So why it shouldn't be equal 1/9?

And if in all n stages I win m time and also i win at stage 1, what is the expected value in stage n.

I can't understand; each stage is independent from other. Isn't it?

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification.  I can only vaguely see where you are going with this.

Comment: @AndrewChin What kind of clarification do you need?

Comment: Let's set $W=\text{win}$. The opposite is losing, and losing can only happen if both of the die return 4 or less; the probability for this is clearly $(4/6)^2$. Therefore, the probability of winning is $1-(4/6)^2 = 5/9$. Can you continue from here?